# Options for tikzcd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-cd

I like to pass options for a specific column (or row) in a tikzcd diagram. The obvious choice `column x/.style=...` does not work. I think the problem is connected with the hierarchy of styles.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
Does not work:
\begin{tikzcd}[column 2/.style=red]
    8 & 1 \\
    3 & 5  \\
    4 & 9  \\
\end{tikzcd}
Does work:
\begin{tikzpicture}[column 2/.style=red]
    \matrix [matrix of nodes]
    {
     8 & 1 \\
     3 & 5  \\
     4 & 9  \\
      };
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: `every matrix/.append style={/tikz/column 2/.style=red}` might already do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\emph{Does} work:
\begin{tikzcd}[/tikz/column 2/.style=red]
    8 & 1 \\
    3 & 5  \\
    4 & 9  \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

We need to specify the full path of the `/tikz/column 2` style because options passed to `{tikzcd}` are executed in the path `/tikz/commutative diagrams`.  The code in your questions creates a style `/tikz/commutative diagrams/column 2`.